# can not migrate using Laravel migrate

Tags: mysql, laravel, macos, sequelpro

I bought new MacBook Pro,i install mysql in it, and then install sequel pro to view the table and database,
but when I command `php artisan migrate` this error accuse
[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0uio.jpg)

almost last 30 hours I am suffering this Problem can any one help see

Comment: Wrong username/password. Is your .env file correct? Check your config/database.php. run php artisan tinker and type `config('database')` and check if your database credentials are correct.

Comment: @EliasSoares yes I thing this is similar problem ,but I can not understand that answer,can you please help me in simple words

Comment: Is your sequel pro connect successfully? if yes @Elias Soares provied you awesome link. I think you can create new user and grant all PRIVILEGES to user that's works fine.

Comment: Yes I do that, i create new user give them all privileges, but that also not working

Comment: How are you serving your Laravel application locally?

Comment: `composer dump-autoload` you may try this command then try your command

Comment: @jeremykenedy application is locally use

Comment: Yeah but how do you serve it locally?

Comment: I simply install mysql `brew install mysql` then install Laravel ,and starting server on port 127.0.0.1:8000

Comment: thanks for the all loving people who helping me,somw how i solve the error,i just uninstall mysql and just re-install with the comand `brew install mysql8.*`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest installing homestead to develop on locally or valet.

https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/homestead
https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/valet

If neither one of those are an option you can try `php artisan serve`

https://laravel.com/docs/master#installing-laravel

Once the application is serving with one of the three options mentioned about you then connect yo your database.

Without serving the application somehow it does not know to connect to localhost from the application.

That is why you get the error message when trying to migrate is because the application doesn't know how to connect to your intallation of MySQL.

Using a virtualized development environment such as homestead with protecting the integrity of your computer (host machine) and allow it to simulate an environment closer to production.